# Unable to create companion class instance in companion object method

Tags: scala, companion-object

What's wrong with this code:

```
class Trivials(s:String){
  private val x = 0
}

object Trivials {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Trivials t = new Trivials("Trivials")
 }
}
```

Both class and object are defined in same source file, hence they are companion.

Error message is as: 'Cannot resolve symbol t'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong syntax (You are using Java syntax) for object creation. In case of Scala you need not mention the type in front of the variable `t` it will be automatically inferred.

```
Trivials t = new Trivials("Trivials")
```

Scala syntax

```
val t = new Trivials("Trivials")
```

Comment: Oops. Java hangover still there.